# Converting links into anchors when displaying data in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, anchor, hyperlink, html-escape-characters

So I have some textual data which contains links, now what is the proper way to convert them into anchors when that data is being displayed.

The one way that I see is to do smth like this `raw(urlize(h(data)))`...
Maybe there is better way?

P.S. I don't want to use redcloth

Answer (score 0):

You can write a method that implements the [Daring Fireball](http://daringfireball.net/2009/11/liberal_regex_for_matching_urls) inspired link matcher:

```
class String
  def urlify
    gsub(%r{\b(([\w-]+://?|www[.])[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))}u) do |s|
      %Q{<a href="#{s}">#{s}</a>}
    end.html_safe
  end
end
```

This will link anything prefixed with the proper protocol like `http://` or `mailto:` though care should be taken to skip or strip `javascript:` links.

Comment: its not a problem for me to convert links to anchors, what is bugging me is that I don't know if it is rational to escape data then urlize it and at the end to return it as raw, so links are rendered.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the auto_link gem [here](https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink)